# Univerality Class and Momentum Space Topology

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superfluidity

I'm very interested in learning about Superfluid Vacuum Theory, and one thing I have come across is the statement that the universality classes are protected by momentum space topology. So I was wondering, what the concept of a universality class is and what exactly is ment by "protected" by momentum space topology?

The simpler terms the better because I'm just starting to learn the subject.

Comment: Did you read Volovik's book *The universe in a helium droplet* at Oxford Publications ? It's the starting point to understand all these. Your question, as is stands, can not be answered, since we have no idea about your background.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Superfluid Vacuum Theory, but I surmise that the answer to your question can be found in the study of nonlinear dynamic systems (SVT being an example).  If a system is linear and conservative, it's motion will be stable and the solutions are called attractors.  If plotted in phase space (the space of all coordinates and their associated momenta) it will probably be some sort of periodic closed loop. This phase space is what you are calling momentum space.

Now if the system is nonlinear or nonconservative or has driving forces that can add or subtract energy from the system, the phase space plots will likely no longer be periodic closed loops. Instead, these phase space plots will likely look like some kind of fractal object. These objects are called strange attractors.

Now frequently, there will be parameters in the equations defining the system (or slight changes in functional forms) that will induce changes in the strange attractor shape but will not alter its topology. These classes of strange attractors (with altered shapes but identical topology) are called universality classes.

This terminology was first introduced by Feigenbaum who discovered a class of nonlinear mapping functions that exhibited a period doubling route to deterministic chaos that nevertheless all exhibited similar behavior.